# PHP - how to parse STRING field (remove some XML elements and all namespaces)?

Tags: php, xml, string

I really need a help about string parsing in field containg not valid XML value.
I will display current value with target value to put in string field.

I have a field $xmlString with this value (elements are NOT in the SEPERATE lines but in the SAME line; it is web service response so I do not have impact on response only on later parsing):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=" http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <p:queryBillingAccountResponse xmlns:p="http://www.ibm.com">
            <ns0:customerAccount xmlns:ns0=" http://www.ibm.com/2009">
                <ComponentCustomerAccount>
                    <Name>ADSL 4</Name>
                    <CharacteristicValue>
                        <Characteristic>
                            <Name>Balance</Name>
                        </Characteristic>
                        <Value>0.0</Value>
                    </CharacteristicValue>
                    <AccountStatus>Paid</AccountStatus>
                </ComponentCustomerAccount>
            </ns0:customerAccount>
        </p:queryBillingAccountResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want this output if this is possible:

```
<queryBillingAccountResponse>
    <customerAccount>
        <ComponentCustomerAccount>
            <Name>ADSL 4</Name>
            <CharacteristicValue>
                <Characteristic>
                    <Name>Balance</Name>
                </Characteristic>
                    <Value>0.0</Value>
                </CharacteristicValue>
            <CharacteristicValue>
            <AccountStatus>Paid</AccountStatus>
        </ComponentCustomerAccount>
    </customerAccount>
</queryBillingAccountResponse>
```

So you will notice that I do not have first three lines (although they are not really seperate lines) and last two lines  and I do not have namespaces defined for `queryBilling AccountResponse` and `customer Account`. I want these elements without namespace to be in string field. For both on start and end tag. I really need this output. How to parse this? I tried with SimpleXMLElement but could not parse it.
Thank you for your help

**Updated output which can not be parsed by $xml = simplexml_load_string($text);**

```
<<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope>
<Body>
<queryBillingAccountResponse>
<customerAccount>
<ComponentCustomerAccount>
<Name>ADSL 4</Name>
<CharacteristicValue>
<Characteristic>
<Name>Balance</Name>
</Characteristic>
<Value>0.0</Value>
</CharacteristicValue>
<AccountStatus>Paid</AccountStatus>
</ComponentCustomerAccount>
</customerAccount>
</queryBillingAccountResponse>
</Body>
</Envelope>
XML>
```

Comment: How is this different from [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15565000/php-how-to-delete-from-variable-that-contains-xml-structure-some-specific-elem)? Why should I not mark this as a duplicate?

Comment: please dont because I do not know how to remove namespaces. It is completely different. thank you for understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have a xml code that SimpleXML can understand, and since you don't need the namespaces declarations, the following code cleans the code before to apply it to `simplexml_load_string`

```
<?php
    // if the XML comes from a file (or just assign the $text string)
    $text = file_get_contents('myfile.xml');
    $text = preg_replace('/(<\s*)\w+:/','$1',$text);   // removes <xxx:
    $text = preg_replace('/(<\/\s*)\w+:/','$1',$text); // removes </xxx:
    $text = preg_replace('/\s+xmlns:[^>]+/','',$text); // removes xmlns:...

    // the code should be clean enough for SimpleXML to parse it
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($text);

    // view the XML (and process it afterwards...)
    print_r($xml);
```

To put the sample XML in a string (instead of a file)

```
    <?php
       $text = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=" http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <p:queryBillingAccountResponse xmlns:p="http://www.ibm.com">
            <ns0:customerAccount xmlns:ns0=" http://www.ibm.com/2009">
                <ComponentCustomerAccount>
                    <Name>ADSL 4</Name>
                    <CharacteristicValue>
                        <Characteristic>
                            <Name>Balance</Name>
                        </Characteristic>
                        <Value>0.0</Value>
                    </CharacteristicValue>
                    <AccountStatus>Paid</AccountStatus>
                </ComponentCustomerAccount>
            </ns0:customerAccount>
        </p:queryBillingAccountResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
XML;

    $text = preg_replace('/(<\s*)\w+:/','$1',$text);   // removes <xxx:
    $text = preg_replace('/(<\/\s*)\w+:/','$1',$text); // removes </xxx:
    $text = preg_replace('/\s+xmlns:[^>]+/','',$text); // removes xmlns:...

    // the code should be clean enough for SimpleXML to parse it
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($text);

    // view the XML (and process it afterwards...)
    print_r($xml);
```

To access elements, use `->` (and `[xx]` for arrays), e.g

```
    echo echo $xml->Body->queryBillingAccountResponse->customerAccount->ComponentCustomerAccount->Name . "\n";
```

will display

```
ADSL 4
```

[SimpleXML doc](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)